# how to export the existing documents stored in a database from MongoDb Atlas free cloud version?

Tags: python, mongodb, csv, export, pymongo

I have stored around 500k documents in a collection in a database on the free cluster available through the free cloud version of MongoDB called MongoDB Atlas. I have a total storage of 512 MB available so i need to delete this data however first i need to export the data into a csv file or excel.

I have just installed the MongoDB shell and am using Pymongo driver to connect to the database. I have not installed MongoDB locally on my machine.

I tried using Mongoexport from the command line but it did not work stating that the command is not recognized. I am using python.

Comment: You need to install mongoexport separately, although you are probably better off using mongodump. Install either using the instructions here: https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/installation/#install-tools

Comment: Is not mongoexport a command to be run from the command line ? why do i need to seperately install it ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you already have the [Command-Line Tool](https://github.com/mongodb/mongocli) installed in your system.

```
mongoexport -h <hostname:port> -d <db name> -c <collection> -u <user> -p <password> -o <output file>
```

Should export a JSON of your collection.
If you want a Binary export for a future restore in a different infrastructure you should use

```
mongodump -h <hostname:port> -d <db name> -c <collection> -u <user> -p <password> -o <output file>
```

Comment: There is a "mongocli" now: https://github.com/mongodb/mongocli. "Command-line tools" is probably a better label.